# Fluent Validation against child collection - how to show error message in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have a parent model that contains a child collections. My validation is working good. I see the error message on the page for the child elements. In the return message from the server, I see that the error for the collection is in the result message, but since the property itself is not mapped in the view, it doesn't bind to the asp-validation-for.

Here is my code:
Models:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public List<TestChildModel> TestChildModels { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TestChildModelsErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class TestChildModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var tModel = new TestModel
        {
            Name = "Test 1",
            TestChildModels = new List<TestChildModel>
            {
                new TestChildModel {Id = 1, Name = "Child 1", Count = 0},
                new TestChildModel {Id = 2, Name = "Child 2", Count = 0},
                new TestChildModel {Id = 2, Name = "Child 3", Count = 0},
            }
        };


        return View(tModel);
    }

    [FormValidator]
    public IActionResult Submit(TestModel testModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return FormResult.CreateSuccessResult("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            return FormResult.CreateErrorResult("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Validators:

```
public class TestModelValidator : AbstractValidator<TestModel>
{
    public TestModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).MaximumLength(10);
        RuleFor(x => x.TestChildModels).Custom((list, context) =>
        {
            if (list.Sum(x => x.Count) < 3)
            {
                context.AddFailure("The 'Count' sum must be greater than 3.");
            }
        });
        RuleForEach(x=>x.TestChildModels).SetValidator(new TestChildModelValidator());
    }
}

public class TestChildModelValidator : AbstractValidator<TestChildModel>
{
    public TestChildModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).MaximumLength(15);
        RuleFor(x => x.Count).GreaterThan(0);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model ItemRequest.WebApplicationMVC.Models.TestModel

<form id="testForm" method="post" asp-formhelper="true" asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Submit">
<input asp-for="Name" />
<span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TestChildModels)
<span asp-validation-for="TestChildModels" class="text-danger"></span>

<input type="submit" value="Soumettre" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

EditorTemplates TestChildModel.cshtml

```
@model ItemRequest.WebApplicationMVC.Models.TestChildModel

<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
    <input asp-for="Id" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <input asp-for="Count" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Count" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the result message I have when I submit.

```
{"status":4,"message":null,"redirectUri":null,"redirectDelay":null,"object":null,
"validationErrors":[
    {"propertyName":"TestChildModels","message":"The \u0027Count\u0027 sum must be greater than 3."}, 
    {"propertyName":"TestChildModels[0].Count","message":"\u0027Count\u0027 doit \u00EAtre plus grand que \u00270\u0027."},
    {"propertyName":"TestChildModels[1].Count","message":"\u0027Count\u0027 doit \u00EAtre plus grand que \u00270\u0027."},
    {"propertyName":"TestChildModels[2].Count","message":"\u0027Count\u0027 doit \u00EAtre plus grand que \u00270\u0027."}],"isSucceed":false}
```

I got error in the javascript files because the form doesn't contain a property called `TestChildModels`.

I explored a couple of solution but no success : put an hidden input for `TestChildModels`, tried to return the error message in another property, but wasn't able to do that.

I'm using FluentValidation and FormHelper in a ASP.NET Core MVC project. FluentValidation : https://fluentvalidation.net/ FormHelper : https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change your code like below:

First add the Error attribute in your class:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public List<TestChildModel> TestChildModels { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public string TestChildModelsErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your `TestModelValidator` like following:

```
public class TestModelValidator : AbstractValidator<TestModel>
{
    public TestModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).MaximumLength(10);
        RuleFor(x => x.TestChildModels).Custom((list, context) =>
        {
            if (list.Sum(x => x.Count) < 3)
            {
                //context.AddFailure("The 'Count' sum must be greater than 3.");
                context.AddFailure(new ValidationFailure("Error", "The 'Count' sum must be greater than 3."));
            }
        });
        RuleForEach(x => x.TestChildModels).SetValidator(new TestChildModelValidator());
    }
}
```

In your view:

```
<form id="testForm" method="post" asp-formhelper="true" asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Submit">
<input asp-for="Name" />
<span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.TestChildModels.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestChildModels[i])
}
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Error"/>
<span asp-validation-for="Error" class="text-danger"></span>

<input type="submit" value="Soumettre" />
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: @Yinqui This doesn't work. The property `TestChildModels` is empty in the validator because the hidden input is kind of overriding the binding of the childs input. If you put a break point in the validator in the custom function, you will see that the list is empty. Did you test a valid condition (that the childs sum is greater than 3) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Great detailed answer :)